# Rewriting a simple fraction to fit the Harmonic series

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, algorithms

I'm refreshing my brain by going through some chapters of CLRS (algorithms bible). One of the first example problems in the appendix (A.1) is showing the harmonic series. But they do a simplification of the fraction that leaves me dumbfounded. I understand the sum, but not how they went from this fraction:

$$\frac{1}{x(x+1)}$$

to this one:

$$\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x+1}$$

I can work it backwards fine, but starting from $\frac{1}{x(x+1)}$ I can't wrap my head around it! What am I forgetting?

The original problem was to find an equation for this harmonic series:

$$\sum_{x=1}^n \frac{1}{x(x+1)}$$

Comment: What about writing the numerator ($1$) as $(x+1)-x$?

Comment: Wow that was fast, thanks. I was thinking of doing that, but it seemed "too easy". Could you explain the intuition behind it? If I see a `+` or `-` in the denominator can I always split it out in a similar way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $$\frac{1}{x(x+1)}=\frac{A}{x}+\frac{B}{x+1}$$ and solve for $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 0):

This generalizes nicely
to the product
of any number of
consecutive integers.

If
$p_n(x)
=x(x+1)...(x+n-1)
=\prod_{j=0}^{n-1} (x+j)
$,
you can get
telescoping sums
for both
$p_n(x)$
and
$\dfrac1{p_n(x)}$.

$\begin{array}\\
p_n(x+1)-p_n(x)
&=\prod_{j=0}^{n-1} (x+1+j)-\prod_{j=0}^{n-1} (x+j)\\
&=\prod_{j=1}^{n} (x+j)-\prod_{j=0}^{n-1} (x+j)\\
&=\prod_{j=1}^{n-1} (x+j)((x+n)-x)\\
&=n\prod_{j=0}^{n-2} (x+1+j)\\
&=np_{n-1}(x+1)
\end{array}
$

and

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac1{p_n(x)}-\dfrac1{p_n(x+1)}
&=\dfrac1{\prod_{j=0}^{n-1} (x+j)}-\dfrac1{\prod_{j=0}^{n-1} (x+1+j)}\\
&=\dfrac1{\prod_{j=0}^{n-1} (x+j)}-\dfrac1{\prod_{j=1}^{n} (x+j)}\\
&=\dfrac1{\prod_{j=0}^{n} (x+j)}((x+n)-x)\\
&=\dfrac{n}{p_{n+1}(x)}\\
\end{array}
$

This last, 
for $n=1$ and $2$ is

$\dfrac1{x}-\dfrac1{x+1}
=\dfrac1{x(x+1)}
$
and
$\dfrac1{x(x+1)}-\dfrac1{(x+1)(x+2)}
=\dfrac{2}{x(x+1)(x+2)}
$.